# struct with a FIFO

Tags: c, struct

I'm having some trouble with structs..

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct filaNo{   
     Range data;   
     struct filaNo* prox; 
  }tfilaNo;                    

typedef struct tfifo {        
     tfilaNo* inicio;   
     tfilaNo* final;       
  } tfifo;
```

And I want to include this list in another struct:

```
typedef struct  
{
int    threadId;
    double threshold;
    double areaCalc;
    tfifo  intervalos;
}ThreadData;
```

When I use only tfifo it works perfectly, but when I include into ThreadData I receive 55 errors (like: "syntax error: identifier 'tfifo'"...) and so many others like this... seems like the compiler is lost.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: some more code :)

tfifo works fine alone, I can do something like this:

```
tfila doc;                                     
Range range;
int a;   

create_fifo(&doc);      

range.p1.x = 0;
range.p2.x = 33;
range.p1.y = 0;
range.p2.y = 0;
range.area = 0;

insert_fifo (&doc, range);   

while(!empty_fifo(doc)){   
    remove_fifo(&doc,&range);         
    printf("    %d\n", range.p2.x);   
}
```

Now I want to include this into ThreadData, because I need a list for every ThreadData struct.

Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : '}'
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tfila'
Error   18  error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier

But the compiler gets totally lost after this... giving me so many errors that doesn't exist...

Comment: Can you add the line that's causing the problem?

Comment: Can you post the whole error message, as well as any other code that might be relevant?

Comment: I just can't add the line because when I change ThreadData to include tfifo Visual Studio returns more than 55 errors oO

Comment: @BrenoRiba I need some extra data. What is the first line the compiler complains about?

Comment: `tfila != tfilaNo`...

Comment: @twalberg It is different... I included some extra information... totally lost hehe

Answer (score 1):

Is this the real code or a typo?

```
typedef struct tfifo {        
 tfilaNo* inicio;   
 tfilaNo* final;
```

} tfifo;

You are using the same name for the struct and the typedef.  Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: That is not a problem. `struct` names and `typedef`s live in different namespaces. It may be confusing, and thus is not considered a good practice, but it is syntactically acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In C , you need Use like this

```
typedef struct struct_name
{
//...
}mytype_t;
```

Modify this

```
typedef struct give_some_name  
{
int    threadId;
    double threshold;
    double areaCalc;
    tfifo  intervalos;
}ThreadData;
```

**EDIT**

Here you are using same name modify this also

```
typedef struct tfifo_t {        
     tfilaNo* inicio;   
     tfilaNo* final;       
  } tfifo;
```

Comment: Actually the name is ThreadData... didn't work when I put in "give_some_name" or at the end of the struct =/

Comment: I included some more details on the post... trying to find myself here hahah

Comment: `Error 2 error C2059: syntax error : '}' Error 1 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tfila'  
Error 18 error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier` self explained.  and you can simply  get rid of these

Comment: But the compiler is just lost, if I remove tfifo  intervalos; from ThreadData ... everything works fine.. oO